# IBOutlet won't display in .xib dropdown selection menu

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5

Am trying to add a segmented control to a single page application, but the property name quoteOpt won't display in the dropdown menu in the .xib file for selection. Have checked the code and can't figure out why.

Any idea why?

Here is the .h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface PDViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *myQuotes;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *movieQuotes;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextView *quoteText;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *quoteOpt;

- (IBAction) quoteButtonTapped:(id)sender;

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you actually providing a UIDatePicker in interface builder? They're very similar in visual appearance and people often switch them without realizing that one is not a subclass of the other.

(if that doesn't work, kick Xcode. Sometimes it gets out of sync between headers and interface builder and needs a restart)

Comment: I have a 3-segment segmented control which I want to connect with the view controller, then hook up to the button. I tried quitting and restarting Xcode, that didn't work.